# urdf from solidworks

Tags: gazebo, urdf, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've exported an urdf model from solidworks, but actually when I spawn my model on gazebo it is not at origin! I need some clue of how to place my model at gazebo's world origin!

Thanx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102126/urdf-from-solidworks/) by [tttbarros](https://answers.ros.org/users/8896/tttbarros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not explicitly stated, but it sounds like you are using the SolidWorks to URDF plugin. Assuming this, when your model is configured in SolidWorks the plugin will place reference coordinate systems at the global origin of the assembly and at the joint origins of each link. When spawned in Gazebo, this global origin is what aligns with the coordinates specified in the launch file. The global origin is taken to be the origin of the assembly in SW, which generally isn't located anywhere meaningful. In SolidWorks, you should either move the model to align with the global_origin reference coordinate system or create a new reference coordinate system closer to where you want the global origin to be.

---

Originally posted by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) with karma: 581 on 2013-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0